# Loading related entities in EF6

Tags: c#, include, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have 3 tables which are related to each others:

`Product` has many `SuggestedPrices`

`Product` has many `ProductPricing`

so i want to retrieve Suggested Prices like so :

```
await ctx.SuggestedPrices
    .OrderByDescending(pp => pp.SuggestionDate)
    .Include(p1 => p1.Customer)
    .Include(p2 => p2.Product)
    .Include(p3 => p3.Product.ProductPricing)
    .ToListAsync()
```

**According to your request:** i added the followings:

Product class :

```
public class Product : ReportingBase {
    // Product-ProductPricing -> One Product has many Prices
    public virtual ICollection<ProductPricing> ProductPricing { get; set; }
    // Product-SuggestedPrices
    public virtual ICollection<SuggestedPrice> SuggestedPrices { get; set; }
}
```

ProductPricing class :

```
public class ProductPricing {
    // ProductPricings-Product
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

SuggestedPrice class:

```
public class SuggestedPrice : EntityBase {
    // SuggestedPrices-Product
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    // SuggestedPrices-Customer
    public virtual ApplicationUser Customer { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

but when i add line `.Include(p3 => p3.Product.ProductPricing)` i get an error which says:

**Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties**

how do i get rid of this error?

thank to your answers

Comment: no, it's not my case, i can't put the `Select` operator on an entity like `Product` @FedericoDipuma

Comment: Add `SuggestedPrice` class to the question, so we have all the elements of your query.

Comment: here you are @FedericoDipuma

Comment: I would be much easier to follow if you use plural names for your collections. Anyway, according to the posted model the `Include` usage is correct and you shouldn't be getting that error. Except if the model is different from what you have shown.

Comment: Are you sure the navigation property `ProductPricings-Product` is correctly configured? Also, as suggested by @Ivan, please use plural names for collections (this is what EF usually expects for conventional based configuration).

Comment: Yeah, you're right i was confused about plural name for `ProductPricing`, by the way I've added the diagram to clear doubts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggling I found out that there's no need to include `Product.ProductPricing` and it's already there:

```
OrgPrice = p.Product.ProductPricing.FirstOrDefault().OrgPrice,
PriceAfterDiscount = p.Product.ProductPricing.FirstOrDefault().Price
```